# How to copy files from one folder to another using Java?

Tags: java, file

How can I copy a file from one folder to another using java? I have tried to use

```
org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(pasteItem, destinationPath);
```

This works if the destination folder does not contain a file with same name. It throws an IOException if I try to paste the file into the folder. However, is there any way to handle this? May be I want to just paste the file with name renamed automatically to pasteItem(1) or something like that. Please suggest.

In fact, I'm getting a new name for the file if the file with same name already exists. I'm not able to figure how to copy the file and then rename. If I rename first and then copy, I'll lose the original file. If I try to copy the file first, then it is giving an exception saying File with same name already exists!

Comment: [Copying a File or Directory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/copy.html)

Comment: You can replace the destination using `Files.copy(src, dst, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);`

Comment: @KennethClark Replacing the file is not what I'm looking for. I need to copy and keep both files

Comment: `file.exists()` method will tell you if the file exists in destination, you could do what Windows does and append *(1)* to the name using a counter. Increment the counter until the file does not exist.

Comment: how to append (1) before copying the file is my question :)
please check the edited part of the question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Java.io.File class.
It has a method that checks if a fill exists.

Example:

```
//create files
File original =new File("C:\\test\\testfile.txt");
File destination =new File("D:\\test\\file.txt");
//check if file exists.
for(int x=0;destination.exists()==true;x++){
//if file exists then add 1 to file name and check if exists again.
destination=new File("D\\test\\file"+x+".txt");

}
//copy file.
Files.copy(origional, destination, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an overloaded version of this method using a boolean flag which will overwrite the destination file if true.

```
public static void copyFileToDirectory(File srcFile,
                   File destDir,
                   boolean preserveFileDate)
                            throws IOException
```

[http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyFileToDirectory(java.io.File, java.io.File, boolean)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyFileToDirectory(java.io.File,%20java.io.File,%20boolean))

Comment: FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(Clipboard.getSystemClipboard().getFiles().get(0), destinationPath, true);

I'm using this, but I'm getting an error.
java.io.IOException: Source 'E:\Workspace\02-TestRepository\TestScript\6\2.json' and destination 'E:\Workspace\02-TestRepository\TestScript\6\2.json' are the same

Comment: @naveenbharadwaj Why are you trying to copy a file onto itself? That doesn't make any sense, right?

Comment: I'm not copying the file to a file. Source is E:\Workspace\02-TestRepository\TestScript\6\2.json. And the destination is E:\Workspace\02-TestRepository\TestScript\6. I checked it in debug mode. However copyFile function is getting called within copyToDirectory and throwing this error. I have no idea why

Answer (score -1):

Please refer this site to copy a file from one folder to another.
http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-move-file-to-another-directory-in-java/

I am not sure about rename the file automatically